# php image type detection

Tags: php

Unable to detect mime type. if I remove `($mime=="image/jpeg" || $mime=="image/pjpeg")`, it could upload the image successfully.

```
$mime = $_FILES['Filedata']['type'];
if((!empty($_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'])) && ($_FILES['Filedata']['error'] == 0)) {
  $filename = basename($_FILES['Filedata']['name']);
  $ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
  if (($ext=="jpg" || $ext=="jpeg") && ($mime=="image/jpeg" || $mime=="image/pjpeg") && ($_FILES["Filedata"]["size"] < 350000)) {
        $newname = $filename;
        if (!file_exists($newname)) {
            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'], "./photo/" . $newname)) {
                echo "It's done! The file has been saved as: ".$newname;
            } else {
                echo "Error: A problem occurred during file upload!";
            }
        } else {echo "Error: File ".$_FILES["uploaded_file"]["name"]." already exists";}
  } else {
     echo "Error: Only .jpg images under 350Kb are accepted for upload";
  }
} else {
    echo "Error: No file uploaded";
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't rely on the type passed from browser. Use `getimagesize()` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `name` and `type` information for uploaded files should be seen as purely informational and **never be used for anything serious**, since it's user supplied information and can easily be spoofed. You should only ever look at the `tmp_name`, `error` and `size` fields to determine if you want to accept a file. To find the actual MIME type of a file, use PHP's built-in functions:

```
if ($file['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE) {
    die('No file uploaded');
}

if ($file['error'] != UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
    die('Error during upload');
}

if (!$file['size'] || !is_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'])) {
    die('File is weird');
}

$extensions = array(IMAGETYPE_GIF => '.gif', IMAGETYPE_JPEG => '.jpg', IMAGETYPE_PNG => '.png');
$exifType = exif_imagetype($file['tmp_name']);
if (!isset($extensions[$exifType])) {
    die('Unsupported file type');
}

$ext = $extensions[$exifType];
$targetDir = '/somewhere/else/';

do {
    $target = $targetDir . uniqid() . $ext;
} while (file_exists($target));

if (!move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $target)) {
    die('Something went wrong');
}

echo 'Yay, uploaded!';
```

Not that you should necessarily use that many `die()` statements though, that's just for demonstration purposes.

Comment: exif consist of a header info in the image? What would happen should the user stripped the info that inset by Photoshop?

Comment: @Macris `exif` looks at certain magic bytes at the beginning of a file that each valid image must have. If it doesn't, it's not a valid image.

Comment: I see, but as where does the $file come from? Don't we need ['FileData']? Would you mind showing me the HTML upload too?

Comment: @Macris That's just a concise example, just imagine I did `$file = $_FILES['Filedata']`.;

Comment: oh great, other most secure way I can think of using ImageMagick to read and write a new image, this will strip out all hidden data and to avoid retain malicious code. Really appreciate your code, I'm rushing to rollout my website!

Comment: @Macris Yes, actually trying to open the file is a good validation too, but if the file is malicious and there are vulnerabilities in the ImageMagick library, this *may* be an insecure thing to do. (I know of no vulnerabilities that could be exploited as such, but be aware of the possibility and never take opening user-uploaded files lightly.)

Comment: getimagesize() should be used in place of exif_imagetype() as it returns mimetype on images and nothing on anything else, even if the file is masquerading as an image

Comment: @Lawrence Good point possibly, but I don't know how much the two really differ internally. I imagine it shouldn't be too hard forge a file that fools both functions.