# php image uploader need it to be simple

Tags: php, image, upload

I need to get this done very quickly. What's an easy way to do image uploading in php...I have a script atm but if an image with the same name comes it'll overwrite it.

Basically I just want to be able to use the form field file to select an image and upload and maybe rename it somehow. Then put the location into a database to retrieve when needed.

Any tips or ideas on how to do this? Don't have a lot of time to get this done.

Comment: What's the current code you use? Adding a simple `if (file_exists($file))` and renaming if it exists should solve your overwriting problems.

Comment: I haven't made the code yet but I know I ran into the problem a while back where it would overwrite the image...how would I go about renaming it?

Comment: See something similar I've written lately: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6066951/php-image-type-detection/6067014#6067014

Comment: Read up: http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

Answer (score 3):

http://www.google.co.za/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=php+image+upload

http://www.plupload.com/ - is also a good way to do this. Doing something

> very quickly ... the easy way

Sounds to me like you are looking for the easy way out. Please remember that we are not here to give you your code solution, but merely as an advisory panel to help you get over some obstacles in your current (already tried to make it work) code. If you read up a bit its real easy, thats the reason for documentation on everything, especially PHP and file uploading.

:)

Comment: doing an assignment for class, I forgot 1 element, it's due fairly soon so it needs to be fairly quick. :P

Comment: I understand. I also had to do stuff for class.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me right now, your script has a security issue as well.

Append a unique hash to the end of the filename before you save it. That way no one can overwrite your files.

Answer (score 0):

Can you just append `uniqid()` to the filename..?

```
$target = "files/";

// Upload the file to directory
$url = basename($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);
$name = str_replace(' ', '_', $url);
$target .= strtolower($name . uniqid());

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target))
{
    echo 'File has been uploaded<br />
    <a href="' . $target . '">http://yoursite.com/directory/' . $target . '</a>';
}
```

Obviously still needs to be made more secure.

Comment: I am using $_FILES on another page to get it and then calling a function with the variable in it...e.g. upload($url) url being basename($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);

The issue is when I get to move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'] how do I do it? as I am doing it in the function...