# what's wrong with the upload code?

Tags: php

```
<?php
    //set where you want to store files
    //in this example we keep file in folder upload
    //$HTTP_POST_FILES['ufile']['name']; = upload file name
    //for example upload file name cartoon.gif . $path will be upload/cartoon.gif
    $path= "upload/".$HTTP_POST_FILES['ufile']['name'];
    if($ufile !=none) {
        if(copy($HTTP_POST_FILES['ufile']['tmp_name'], $path)) {
            echo "Successful<BR/>";
            //$HTTP_POST_FILES['ufile']['name'] = file name
            //$HTTP_POST_FILES['ufile']['size'] = file size
            //$HTTP_POST_FILES['ufile']['type'] = type of file
            echo "File Name :".$HTTP_POST_FILES['ufile']['name']."<BR/>";
            echo "File Size :".$HTTP_POST_FILES['ufile']['size']."<BR/>";
            echo "File Type :".$HTTP_POST_FILES['ufile']['type']."<BR/>";
            echo "<img src="$path" width="150" height="150">";
        } else {
            echo "Error";
        }
    }
?>
```

it is an toturial form here http://tutorialblog.info/2010/08/06/php-upload-single-file.html
when i tried in my local environment. it displays an error? what's wrong with the code? thank you.

first, i think this is wrong.   `if($ufile !=none)` it should be   `if($_POST['ufile' !=none)`
am i right?

Comment: Honestly, the example code is terrible.  `if($ufile !=none)` doesn't even look like standard PHP.  You're basically checking if `$ufile` is not equal to the constant `none`.  I'd find a better tutorial.

Comment: use `$_FILES` instad of `$HTTP_POST_FILES`. Where initialization of `$ufile` ? Why do you need it anyway? You should `foreach ($_FILES as $file) { /* do stuff with file */ }`

Comment: $ufile is synonymous with $_REQUEST['ufile'] when `register_globals` is on.

Comment: undefine variable $HTTP_POST_FILES. constant none-  in line 8, undefined variable:ufile...

Comment: Stephen ,could you give me more better tutorial links. thank you.

Comment: Something similar I've written recently: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6066951/php-image-type-detection/6067014#6067014 Hope it can serve as inspiration.

Comment: looks like register globals are on for the example, so pretty much wouldn't work on most hosts nowadays, bad example! do another google search

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with Stephen, this is not a good example, you also need to validate your upload. you are not going to allow anyone to upload anything.

but if you want just find the issues: well HTTP_POST_FILES  is no longer accepted by PHP newer versions.   should be $_FILES

$ufile !=none  can be if ($_FILES['ufile']['tmp_name'])

copy($HTTP_POST_FILES['ufile']['tmp_name'], $path)   better be move_uploaded_file($_FILES['ufile']['tmp_name'], $path)

Your html form enctype should be enctype="multipart/form-data"

the $path path should have the right permission